# Big Oh for while loop with empty body. For instance, used here in partition method of Quick Sort

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Came across this implementation of partition method for quick sort, and
**was wondering what would be the Big Oh here**, as it was using nested loops, although inner loop has empty body?

```
public static int partition(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
    int pivot = arr[start];
    int i = start;
    int j = end;

    while (i<j) {
        while (i<j && arr[--j] >= pivot) ;
        if (i<j) {
            arr[i] = arr[j];
        }

        while (i<j && arr[++i] <= pivot) ;
        if (i<j) {
            arr[j] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    arr[j] = pivot;
    return j;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An "empty" body of a loop does not equal "empty" code and "no work" being done. Here it is a `while` loop, but a `for` loop can also have an "empty" body.

So these are still loops, they just do all the work inside their condition part of the loop declaration.

This `while` loop

```
while (i<j && arr[--j] >= pivot);
```

still does some work. It does the `i<j` comparison and if it is `true` it does `--j` and uses the new decreased `j` value to compare `arr[j] >= pivot` and if this is also `true` it keeps going (repeats this all over again - note that `j` has a lower value after each iteration).

So in the worst case this is O(length of arr), when `i` is `0` (start) and `--j` is `arr.length - 1` (end) and `pivot` is the smallest value in the array `arr`.

The function `partition(int[] arr, int start, int end)` is not only called at the start, but also again in recursive calls of the main `quicksort(int[] arr, int start, int end)` call. So `start` being `0` and `end` being at the end of the array `arr` only happens in the beginning, in recursive calls, `start` and `end` cover smaller and smaller parts of the array.

So in a general case it would be O(end - start) where `end - start` is `<= arr.length`.

Eventually `start < end` and thus `i<j` is not `true` anymore and then this loop is not even reached anymore, due to the `i<j` check that is done by the outer `while` loop. Only at that point (at those recursion levels) it does no work anymore.